# How to calculate Eb(k) of networks with Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, social-networking, networkx, correlation

In the paper titled **Scaling of degree correlations and its influence on diffusion in scale-free networks**, the authors define the quantity of $E_b(k)$  to measure the extent of degree correlations.

[image]

[image]

#### Paper

L. K. Gallos, C. Song, and H. A. Makse, Scaling of Degree Correlations and Its Influence on Diffusion in Scale Free Networks, Phys. Rev. Lett. 100, 248701 (2008).

You can read the article following [this link](http://www-levich.engr.ccny.cuny.edu/webpage/hmakse/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2015/06/2008_ScalingofDegree.pdf) or read the related [google book](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=ejtxFdBQ-XEC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=%27Eb(k)%27%20Degree%20correlations&source=bl&ots=NmkTNUjRxi&sig=NpPfduYPKAM8Na4tI8CwOH_UOMQ&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXy4Se4vTNAhWELpQKHbBYD3UQ6AEIRTAE#v=onepage&q&f=true).

#### Question

[image]

My question is how to calculate Eb(k) of networks with Python? My problem is I can't reproduce the results of the authors. I test it using the Condense Matter data. The result of Eb(k) is showed in the figure above. **You can see that one problem in my figure is the Eb(k) is much larger than 1!**!! I have also tried the Internet (As level data) and the WWW data, and the problem persists. No doubt, there is something seriously wrong with my algorithm or code. You can reproduce my results, and compare it with the authors'. Your solution or suggestion are highly appreciated. I will introduce my algorithm and python script below.

#### I follow the following steps:

1. For each edge, to find the edges whose k=k, and k' > 3k. The probability of these edges is denoted as P(k, k')
2. For node, to get the proportion of nodes whose degree is larger than b*k, which is denoted as p(k'), thus we can also have k'*p(k')
3. To get the numerator P1: p1 = \sum P(k, k')/k'*P(k')
4. To get the denominator p2：P2 = \sum P(k')
5. Eb(k) = p1/p2

#### Python script

The python script is given below：

```
%matplotlib inline
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

def ebks(g, b):
    edge_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    degree_dict = defaultdict(int)
    edge_degree = [sorted(g.degree(e).values()) for e in g.edges()]
    for e in edge_degree:
        edge_dict[e[0]][e[-1]] +=1
    for i in g.degree().values():
        degree_dict[i] +=1
    edge_number = g.number_of_edges()
    node_number = g.number_of_nodes()
    ebks, ks = [], []
    for k1 in edge_dict:
        p1, p2 = 0, 0
        for k2 in edge_dict[k1]:
            if k2 >= b*k1:
                pkk = float(edge_dict[k1][k2])/edge_number
                pk2 = float(degree_dict[k2])/node_number
                k2pk2 = k2*pk2
                p1 += pkk/k2pk2
        for k in degree_dict:
            if k>=b*k1:
                pk = float(degree_dict[k])/node_number
                p2 += pk
        if p2 > 0:
            ebks.append(p1/p2)
            ks.append(k1)
    return ebks, ks
```

I test with the ca-CondMat data, you can download it from this url: http://snap.stanford.edu/data/ca-CondMat.html

```
# Load the data
# Remember to change the file path to your own
ca = nx.Graph()
with open ('/path-of-your-file/ca-CondMat.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0] != '#':
            x, y = line.strip().split('\t')
            ca.add_edge(x,y)
nx.info(ca)

#calculate ebk 
ebk, k = ebks(ca, b=3)

plt.plot(k,ebk,'r^')
plt.xlabel(r'$k$', fontsize = 16)
plt.ylabel(r'$E_b(k)$', fontsize = 16)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

**Update**: The problem has not been solved yet.

```
def ebkss(g, b, x):
    edge_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    degree_dict = defaultdict(int)
    edge_degree = [sorted(g.degree(e).values()) for e in g.edges()]
    for e in edge_degree:
        edge_dict[e[0]][e[-1]] +=1
    for i in g.degree().values():
        degree_dict[i] +=1
    edge_number = g.number_of_edges()
    node_number = g.number_of_nodes()
    ebks, ks = [], []
    for k1 in edge_dict:
        p1, p2 = 0, 0
        nk2k = np.sum(edge_dict[k1].values())
        pk1 = float(degree_dict[k1])/node_number
        k1pk1 = k1*pk1
        for k2 in edge_dict[k1]:
            if k2 >= b*k1:
                pk2k = float(edge_dict[k1][k2])/nk2k
                pk2 = float(degree_dict[k2])/node_number
                k2pk2 = k2*pk2
                p1 += (pk2k*k1pk1)/k2pk2
        for k in degree_dict:
            if k>=b*k1:
                pk = float(degree_dict[k])/node_number
                p2 += pk
        if p2 > 0:
            ebks.append(p1/p2**x)
            ks.append(k1)
    return ebks, ks
```

Comment: One difference is that it looks like the published paper used bins that grew for larger k.  This is why the published paper has equally spread out symbols with the logscale on x while yours get more and more dense.  The issue of bigger than 1 is something else.  I'll try to take a look later, but hopefully someone will have solved it by then.

Comment: They may use log-binning for the www, internet, and protein data.

Comment: Note that the networks are first "renomalized" using the box-covering method in [10] C. Song, L. K. Gallos, S. Havlin, and H. A. Makse, J. Stat.
Mech. (2007) P03006.

Comment: In the caption for their figure they say "The data have been vertically shifted in order to show the invariance."  Your comment about your figure: "You can see that one problem in my figure is the Eb(k) is much larger than 1!!"  It's not clear to me that this expression cannot be much larger than 1.

Comment: Only the internet data has been renormalized to show the invariance. They vertically shifted the y axis by starting from 0.01 rather than 0.

Answer (score 3):

According to the paper, the purpose of Eb(k) is to get the correlation exponent epsilon: "[We] introduce a scale-invariant quantity Ebk to
simplify the estimation of epsilon" (second page, bottom of first column).

I haven't found a way to make Eb(k) < 1, but I have found a correction that **computes epsilon correctly**.

According to equation 4, Eb(k) ~ k^-(epsilon-gamma) (where the degree distribution P(k) ~ k^-gamma, a power-law). Thus, if we plot the slope of log(Eb(k)) against log(k), we should get gamma - epsilon. Knowing gamma, we can then easily get epsilon.

Note that this slope is invariant if Eb(k) is scaled by a constant. Thus, the **problem** with your computed Eb(k) **is not** that it's greater than 1, but that it gives you a log-slope of about .5 with k, whereas in the paper the slope is about 1.2, hence you will get the **wrong epsilon**.

## **My Algorithm**

I started off by copying your code, looking over it, and re-implementing it in an equivalent way. My re-implementation replicated your results. I'm quite confident that you implemented the discrete version of the formula for E_b(k) correctly. However, a close examination of the paper suggests that the authors used smooth approximations in their code.

On the second page and column, the equality P(k|k') = P(k, k')/ (k')^(1-gamma) is stated. This is equivalent to replacing the exact probability P(k') in the denominator of the first integral with the smooth power-law approximation (k')^(-gamma) of the degree distribution, and is *not* an equality.

The fact that the authors state this approximation as an equality without qualification suggests to me that they may have used it as such in their code. So, I decided to use their approximation in code, resulting in the below (where I got gamma = 2.8 for cond-mat is explained below).

```
def ebkss(g, b, gamma=2.8):
    edge_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    degree_dict = defaultdict(int)
    edge_degree = [sorted(g.degree(e).values()) for e in g.edges()]
    for e in edge_degree:
        edge_dict[e[0]][e[-1]] +=1
    for i in g.degree().values():
        degree_dict[i] +=1
    edge_number = g.number_of_edges()
    node_number = g.number_of_nodes()
    ebks, ks = [], []
    for k1 in edge_dict:
        p1, p2 = 0, 0
        nk2k = np.sum(edge_dict[k1].values())
        pk1 = float(degree_dict[k1])/node_number
        k1pk1 = k1*pk1

        for k2 in edge_dict[k1]:
            if k2 >= b*k1:
                pk2k = float(edge_dict[k1][k2])/edge_number
                pk2 = float(degree_dict[k2])/node_number
                p1 += pk2k/(k2*k2**(-gamma))
        for k in degree_dict:
            if k>=b*k1:
                pk = float(degree_dict[k])/node_number
                p2 += pk
        if p2 > 0 and p1 > 0:
            ebks.append(p1/p2)
            ks.append(k1)
    return ebks, ks
```

### **The Results**

Using this code:

```
def get_logslope(x,y):
    A = np.empty((len(x), 2))
    A[:,0] = np.log(x)
    A[:,1] = 1
    res = la.lstsq(A, np.log(y))
    return res[0]

def show_eb(ca, b, gamma):
    #calculate ebk 
    ebk, k = ebkss(ca, b=b,gamma=gamma)
    print "Slope = ", get_logslope(np.array(k), np.array(ebk) )
    plt.plot(k,ebk,'r^')
    plt.xlabel(r'$k$', fontsize = 16)
    plt.ylabel(r'$E_b(k)$', fontsize = 16)
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.show()
show_eb(ca, 3, 2.8)
```

I got this output:

```
Slope =  1.22136715547
```

[image: Plot of Eb(k) for the cond-mat network]

The slope (up to 1 digit after the decimal point, which is all that is given in the paper) is correct, and hence epsilon can now be computed correctly.

#### **About Gamma**

I got the value of gamma = 2.8 from adding the slope of 1.2 to the epsilon value of 1.6 (this follows from equation 4 of the paper). I also did a quick sanity check using the powerlaw Python module to determine if this gamma was a decent fit.

```
import powerlaw
res = powerlaw.Fit(np.array(ca.degree().values())+1, xmin=10)
print res.alpha
```

This output

```
2.84571139756
```

thus 2.8 is correct for the value of gamma up to rounding.

### **Edit with WWW data**

I tested out my method with the WWW dataset. I ended up getting a slope that was close to the one in the paper, but the scaling is still off. 
Here's my code:

```
def log_binning(x, y, bin_count=50):
    max_x = np.log10(max(x))
    max_y = np.log10(max(y))
    max_base = max([max_x,max_y])
    xx = [i for i in x if i>0]
    min_x = np.log10(np.min(xx))
    bins = np.logspace(min_x,max_base,num=bin_count)
    hist = np.histogram(x,bins)[0]
    nonzero_mask = np.logical_not(hist==0)       
    hist[hist==0] = 1
    bin_means_y = (np.histogram(x,bins,weights=y)[0] / hist)
    bin_means_x = (np.histogram(x,bins,weights=x)[0] / hist)
    return bin_means_x[nonzero_mask],bin_means_y[nonzero_mask]
def single_line_read(fname):    
    g = nx.Graph()
    with open(fname, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
          a = map(int,line.strip().split(" "))
          g.add_edge(a[0], a[1])
    return g

www = single_line_read("data/www.dat")
ebk, k = ebkss(www, 3, 2.6)
lk, lebk = log_binning(np.array(k,dtype=np.float64), np.array(ebk), bin_count=70)
#print lk, lebk
print "Slope", get_logslope(lk, lebk)
plt.plot(lk,lebk/www.number_of_edges(),'r^')
plt.xlabel(r'$k$', fontsize = 16)
plt.ylabel(r'$E_b(k)$', fontsize = 16)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Slope 0.162453554297
[image: WWW data]

The slope from the original paper is 0.15. I got the gamma value of 2.6 by looking at Figure 3 in the paper (the gamma-epsilon chart).

### **In Conclusion**

I'm not sure why Eb(k) is so much smaller than 1 in the paper's graphic. I'm pretty sure some rescaling is going on that's not explicit in the paper. However, I was able to recover the correct value of epsilon using Eb(k). As long as you're able to compute epsilon correctly, I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: This is the the link of the WWW data http://www3.nd.edu/~networks/resources/www/www.dat.gz

Comment: Also remember to log-binning the data, you can use the log-binning function below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38408979/912429

Comment: I suspect the authors simply change this line: pk = float(degree_dict[k])/node_number to: pk = float(degree_dict[k])

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm going to test out the WWW data, and look into your suggestions.

Comment: @FrankWang The authors might have replaced pk = float(degree_dict[k])/node_number with pk = float(degree_dict[k]). However, that would just scale everything down, and would not solve the problem of getting the wrong slope.

Comment: any progress? Stackoverflow tells me that I have to award the bounty within 24 hours.

Comment: I figured out the log-binning problem. I suspect fixing it will provide a solution (as the computed slope will be different). Perhaps the solution is to log-bin and then scale down as you suggest. I'm going to try it out.

Comment: I've tested out my method on the www data, and I got log-binning to work. I've edited the answer accordingly. Log-binning gets me the correct slope (about) for www.

Answer (score 0):

Considering to use the log-binning of the data, the following the function can be adopted.

```
import numpy as np

def log_binning(x, y, bin_count=35):
    max_x = np.log10(max(x))
    max_y = np.log10(max(y))
    max_base = max([max_x,max_y])
    xx = [i for i in x if i>0]
    min_x = np.log10(np.min(xx))
    bins = np.logspace(min_x,max_base,num=bin_count)
    bin_means_y = (np.histogram(x,bins,weights=y)[0] / np.histogram(x,bins)[0])
    bin_means_x = (np.histogram(x,bins,weights=x)[0] / np.histogram(x,bins)[0])
    return bin_means_x,bin_means_y
```

If you wanna to linearly bin the data, use the following function:

```
def LinearBinData(x, y, number): 
    data=sorted(zip(x,y))
    rs = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),number)
    rs = np.transpose(np.vstack((rs[:-1],rs[1:])))
    ndata = []
    within = []
    for start,end in rs:
        for i,j in data:
            if i>=start and i<end:
                within.append(j)
        ndata.append([(start+end)/2.0,np.mean(np.array(within))]  )
    nx,ny = np.array(ndata).T
    return nx,ny
```

Usually, for the scaling relationship, log-binning would be a better choice.

Comment: You should probably move this into your question.

Comment: Your log binning function throws a zero division error when I try to use it with my data. I'm trying to track down the issue. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are actually computing the conditional probability using discrete distributions, so you are getting lots of zeros, which creates problems.

In the paper (top of second column, second page) it looks like they are using a power law fit to the data to replace the noisy discrete values with a nice smooth function.  And that's also, I assume, why they write E_b in terms of integrals rather than summations.

If I were you, I would ask the authors of the paper for their code.  And then I would ask the journal to stop publishing papers without supporting code.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question about how to do the calculation.

Comment: @pat it's mutual :)